# Python group by values using itertools groupby function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Python code is below.

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 4), ('c', 5)]
_sorted_data = sorted(data,key= lambda element : element[0])
_res = groupby(_sorted_data,key=lambda x : x[0])
for key,value in _res:
    print(key,list(value))
```

Got below result.

```
a [('a', 1)]
b [('b', 2), ('b', 3)]
c [('c', 4), ('c', 5)]
```

my expected result is

```
a [1]
b [2,3]
c [4,5]
```

How can transform the 'Values'

Comment: instead of print , can we control at groupby function at level

Comment: can we do like this { key : [element[1] for element in value] for key,value in _res }

Comment: @LearnHadoop, we can not control at groupby function at level because when you look at how groupby is implemented, it gives back pairs like `(current_key, group_by_iterator)`. You can find more information on this by checking out the following link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby.

Comment: `{ key : [element[1] for element in value] for key, value in _res }` you can definitely do this if you are fine with the dictionary output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your actual input is unsorted since you're calling `sorted` first in your code, resulting in an overall time complexity of *O(n log n)* despite a linear time complexity when performing `itertools.groupby`.

You can instead iterate over the input list and aggregate the items in a dict for an overall linear time complexity:

```
data = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 4), ('c', 5)]
result = {}
for key, value in data:
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
for key, values in result.items():
    print(key, values)
```

This outputs:

```
a [1]
b [2, 3]
c [4, 5]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/1D7gRS